# off-diagonal elements of projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question on projection matrices.
If $A$ is a projection matrix(i.e. $A$ is symmetric and $A^2=A$). I want to prove that $|a_{ij}|\leq1/2$ for $i\neq j$. I proved that the diagonal elements $a_{ii}\in[0,1]$, but I don't know how to prove the off-diagonal parts. Any suggestions?

Comment: Projection matrices aren’t necessarily symmetric, e.g., $\pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}$ is a projection. What you’re asking about are matrices that represent _orthogonal_ projection.

Comment: Also, I suspect that if your conjecture is true, that it’s only going to be true for certain scalar products, such as the Euclidean scalar product. For instance, the matrix representing orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{span}\{(1,1,0)^T,(0,-1,1)^T\}$ relative to the scalar product given by the matrix $\pmatrix{2&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&4}$ isn’t symmetric and has off-diagonal elements $> 1/2$.